# iOS app compiling and MacInCloud/similar

Tags: ios, delphi, cross-compiling, delphi-xe4

I am contemplating developing iOS apps use Delphi XE4 with iOS. In my research I saw MacInCloud, http://www.macincloud.com/features/tools/tools

Does anyone have practical experience with this? Can I hook up my Windows/Delphi/similar development tool to MacInCloud/xCode for cross compiling (to obey licensing terms) and have the app debugged on my iPhone?

Maybe over time it would be beneficial to buy an iMac, but if I could start creating apps without it would be great.

Comment: The problematic bit in this configuration would be debugging on the iPhone, since the simplest way to transfer an app to an iOS device is to connect the device to a Mac, which is this case is in the Cloud.

Answer (score 4):

I recently tried exactly that with MacInCloud. XCode and Delphi XE4's PAServer is now automatically installed by MacInCloud so I had few issues hooking up my Windows and Delphi environment.

What I found was that running and debugging in the iOS simulator on the Mac in the cloud worked fine. However as my upload speed was quite slow a compilation took some considerable time. Each compilation seemed to require an upload of about 17MB for the app and another 50MB for the debug symbols.

There is no way of plugging in your iPhone into the mac in the cloud and MacInCloud therefore recommend that you use a further cloud provider (TestFlightApp.com) to deploy the app to your device. I couldn't test using the TestFlightApp service as I have not signed up for the required developer account with Apple and so cannot deploy to physical devices at all.

All in all, if I was doing serious work I would either buy a Mac or pay for faster upload speeds but despite that I found it an very educational experience.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. If anyone has experience if debugging on iPhone actually can work with cloud settups, I would appreciate it. I will return to this SO later, and probably mark your question as answer since it was very spot on what I needed.

Comment: I'm now using macincloud for Delphi XE6 with iOS. They are officially recommended by Embarcadero and the server speed is much faster now for XE6. I had the same compilation issue a while back with XE5, which takes forever to complete. It is fine now, maybe macincloud or XE6 has fixed the bug.

Comment: I used macincloud and I was fedup with it. It can be a temporary solution but if you are getting serious with development then leave it. I bought a Mac Mini on monthly installment basis and I'm paying almost similar to what I was paying to macincloud. It works just fine for me. Go for mac mini if your budget is tight. It'll be much better than mac in cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Good luck with TestFlightApp. That is one of those great services we use to have but not anymore. It use to work at one time but has fallen in great disrepair and been neglected.
Even if that did work, you would go out of you mind if you was working on something that can only run on the device. Not all iOS features work on simulator, like in app purchase for instance.
Where with a real machine at hand it deploys right to device almost as fast as simulator. Just a few seconds longer. Doing it this other way would take 15 minutes or more and require many steps of your interaction. You will forget where you left off in your code by that time.